# how to open eclipse console output in command prompt

Tags: c

I am using eclipse oxygen IDE to practice c programming. I found that eclipse console window is not functioning as I want so! is there any way to open the output directly in command prompt window instead of inbuilt eclipse console.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I Understood from your question.

*You want to open the output of your c program in command prompt*

It's pretty simple. Just go the directory in which your executable is stored and run the .exe file

```
<path>filename.exe
```

---

If however you want to start eclipse from cmd you would have to add the `bin` folder to the `PATH` environment variable.